# How to iterate with for loop over numbers starting with 0 in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to iterate with `for loop` through 8 digit numbers starting with 0. For example, the first number is: `00000000` and I would like to display next 5 numbers.
So far I managed to accomplish sth. like that:

```
<?php

     $start = 00000000;
     $number = 5;

     for ($i = $start; $i < $start + $number; $i++) {
        $url = sprintf("http://test.com/id/%08d", $i);
        echo $url . "\r\n";
     }
?>
```

Result:

```
http://test.com/id/00000000
http://test.com/id/00000001
http://test.com/id/00000002
http://test.com/id/00000003
http://test.com/id/00000004
```

There's everything fine with this example, however, problems start with such an example:

```
<?php

         $start = 00050200;
         $number = 5;

         for ($i = $start; $i < $start + $number; $i++) {
            $url = sprintf("http://test.com/id/%08d", $i);
            echo $url . "\r\n";
         }
    ?>
```

The for loop produces:

```
http://test.com/id/00020608
http://test.com/id/00020609
http://test.com/id/00020610
http://test.com/id/00020611
http://test.com/id/00020612
```

while I expect:

```
http://test.com/id/00050200
http://test.com/id/00050201
http://test.com/id/00050202
http://test.com/id/00050203
http://test.com/id/00050204
```

Comment: In PHP, numbers starting with a `0` are octal.

Comment: Just initialise $start=0 as the sprintf is doing the formatting for you.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work because numbers beginning with a 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. From the [Integers page of the PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) (Emphasis mine) :

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16),
>   octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a
>   sign (- or +).
>
> Binary integer literals are available since PHP 5.4.0.
>
> **To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero)**. To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
>   notation precede the number with 0b.

Simply use :

```
 $start = 50200;
```

At the beginning of your code and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get other numbers is that a leading zero makes your number octal. So you start by setting `$start = 00050200;`, this makes `$start` octal.

Just remove these leading zeroes and the code will be fine.